# jQuery child of parent class change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using FontAwesome, and have an icon within my accordion.  So, I have a plus icon, and a minus icon.  When the class becomes an 'active-header', then I want it to change the icon of that h2 only.  I'm just not really sure how to do it, here's my fiddle & code.

[Check my Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/J3Rgg/)

```
$('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
$('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });


$('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
$('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');


$('.accordion-header').click(function () {
    if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
        $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
    }
    else {
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        $(this)
    }
});

return false;
```

I do think that it would be done with .parent & .child, but I'm not really sure on how to go about it.

---Edit---

The I code for the minus icon is:

```
<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

JS:

```
$('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');  
var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
$('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth }); 
$('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
$('.accordion-header').first().find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
$('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');    
$('.accordion-header').click(function () {
if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
    $('.active-header').find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
    $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
    }
    else {
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        $(this)
    }
});

return false;
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/J3Rgg/10/)

Comment: Adding the MINUS (to the css) was not necessary, it fired up perfectly with the jQuery change only.  This was the most acceptable answer because it also fired up the 'minus' icon on the focus of the original parent (on page load).  Plus, now I know about the find function! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
$('.accordion-content').css({
    'width': contentwidth
});


$('.accordion-header').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
        $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header inactive-header').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
    }
}).first().click();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6pRGG/)

Comment: That is a good option, but does not replace the icon when it is toggled again.  I won't down vote because it was helpful.  Someone else did down vote, it was not me.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you should look at in your code, it would make a lot of sense to save some of the elements you work with to variables and to just kind of clean up the code some. The answers above work however you should also look at optimizing your code for performance.

JS:

```
var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();

var accTitles = $( '.accordion-header' );
var accContents = $( '.accordion-content' );


accTitles
    .first()
    .addClass('active-header');

accContents
    .first()
    .slideDown( 300 )
    .addClass('open-content');


accTitles.on('click', function ( e ) {
    var self = $( this );

    if(self.hasClass('active-header')) {
        self
            .removeClass('active-header')
            .children('i')
            .removeClass('fa-minus')
            .addClass('fa-plus');
        self
            .next()
            .slideUp(300)
            .removeClass('open-content');
    }
    else {
        accContents
            .slideUp(300)
            .removeClass('open-content');

        accTitles
            .removeClass('active-header')
            .children('i')
            .removeClass('fa-minus')
            .addClass('fa-plus');

        self
            .addClass('active-header')
            .children('i')
            .removeClass('fa-minus')
            .addClass('fa-plus');
        self
            .next()
            .slideDown(300)
            .addClass('open-content');
    }
});
```

Hope this is useful!

Here is a fiddle to show it is working code :: http://jsfiddle.net/kkemple/M32fa/7/

Comment: The changing of the icon doesn't work though.  Do you have a good link to where I could really look into this styling of doing things.  It's a lot longer,  but a lot cleaner.

Comment: the icon classes just needed to be reversed. As far this style of coding is concerned there are a few places to get started. Start with David Crockford's "JavaScript the Good Parts". What i like to do is check out how the top developers in the industry are doing things and try to figure out why they are doing it.

Comment: also as far as being longer, cleaner and easier to read will always win out, which one of these examples will be easiest to read 6 months from now when you have to make an update. also length should not be an issue as you will want to minify your code before releasing it to production as well

Comment: Yeah, I had planned on offering the minified versions with the template, and having offering the original.  Thank you, I will read up on David Crockfords guide.  I will be coding up a nice little content toggle today for the admin panel.  (links on left, and content on right) so I will make a good attempt at using this style.

Comment: I got it to change the 'icon' with ease, and even on the .first() change the icon as well.  I want to really thank you, I appreciate your help, even after the answer was selected.

Comment: Ah darn, I did have one problem... multiple instances.  I tried adding two, and they merge as 1.  :(

Comment: yeah for that you need better separation, right now your selectors will get every title and content on the page and affect them, you need to isolate them to a container, however to be able to use the same functions on them you need to create a factory function to return the individual accordian instances, here is a jsfiddle with a working example of multiple instances :: http://jsfiddle.net/kkemple/M32fa/10/

Comment: Woah, that just got way more complicated.. I'm really going to have to dig into this to get a better understanding. Thank you for the comments, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

    var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
    $('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });


    $('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
    $('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');


    $('.accordion-header').click(function () {
        if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
            $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');

            $(this).parent().find('.inactive-header').find('.fa-minus').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
            $(this).find('.fa-plus').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().find('.active-header').find('.fa-minus').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
            $(this)
        }
    });

    return false;
```

Comment: This is also a good option, but does not have the minus icon on the original focus of the first parent.  But very good option to start from, I will not down vote as this is still a good answer. (upvoted)